# OSM routing on ferry lines

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I am building a tool that aims to display and store public transport trips. I currently have train, bus and air travel working, and I would like to add ferry.

For Bus, I currently use the OSRM. For train, I use a custom version of the OSRM that uses tracks instead of roads. And for air, I simply plot a geodesic between the airports.

I am at a bit of a loss concerning the ferries. In OSM, they are stored as either [relations](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/563319) or [ways](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/190568784), but I don't know how I could find only the part between 2 points.

Would anyone have an idea of how to get this ?

Comment: OSRM already supports ferry lines. See for example here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_foot&route=51.01106%2C13.86346%3B51.01009%2C13.86195

Comment: @scai Yes but how do I specify only ferry lines ? Like, [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_foot&route=63.4430%2C10.4069%3B69.6466%2C18.9582#map=8/62.876/10.234) for example, there is a ferry line between the two, but it's ignored by OSRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running another OSRM server with a ferry.lua like so :

```lua
api_version = 4

Set = require('lib/set')
Sequence = require('lib/sequence')
Handlers = require("lib/way_handlers")

function setup()
  local ferry_speed = 30  -- ferry speed in km/h
  return {
    properties = {
      weight_name                   = 'duration',
      max_speed_for_map_matching    = 30/3.6,  -- kmph -> m/s
      call_tagless_node_function    = false,
      use_turn_restrictions         = false,
    },

    default_mode            = mode.ferry,
    default_speed           = ferry_speed,
    oneway_handling         = 'ignore',  -- allow traversal in both directions

    -- Only allow ways tagged as ferry route
    access_tag_whitelist = Set {
      'ferry'
    },

    speeds = Sequence {
      route = {
        ferry = ferry_speed,
      }
    },
  }
end

function process_node(profile, node, result)
  -- empty, ferry routes are mainly defined by ways, not nodes
end

function process_way(profile, way, result)
  -- only consider ways tagged with 'route=ferry'
  local is_ferry = way:get_value_by_key('route')
  if is_ferry == 'ferry' then
    result.forward_mode = mode.ferry
    result.backward_mode = mode.ferry
    result.forward_speed = profile.default_speed
    result.backward_speed = profile.default_speed
  else
    result.forward_mode = mode.inaccessible
    result.backward_mode = mode.inaccessible
  end
end

return {
  setup = setup,
  process_way =  process_way,
  process_node = process_node,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Valhalla comes with built-in support for ferries. You can [try it](https://valhalla.openstreetmap.de/directions?profile=car&wps=7.267456054687501%2C43.67979094030124%2C8.399047851562502%2C40.83874913796459) using the public instance hosted on openstreetmap.

It also lets you define custom preference and waiting time for ferries, as specified in the [API reference](https://valhalla.github.io/valhalla/api/turn-by-turn/api-reference/#costing-options).

If you really only want to route on ferry lines, you would probably have to build a custom graph from an OSM extract that only includes ferry lines.